# Display text array using UmbracoHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco7

I can't figure out how to display a text array in Umbraco.  I'm trying to show values from a "Repeatable Text String" property in a razor view.

I have an Umbraco view set up which passes through a model like so:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<MyModel>
```

This means that I can't access umbraco fields through Model.someVariable the normal way. Instead, I have been using UmbracoHelper to display text content like this:

```
@Umbraco.Field("mainColour")
```

But this doesn't work with the "repeatable text strings" property type, as .Field() converts it to an IHtmlString.

How can I display all the text strings on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Is your model a ModelsBuilder model? If so, you should be able to do:

```
@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("mainColour")
```

To turn the property into an array of strings, that syntax can be altered to:

```
@(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<string>>("mainColour"))
```

You may need to install the Core Property values converter to get that to work.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I populate Model with a MyModel instead.  I am looking for a way to do that without using @Model.

Comment: Is MyModel mapped from the current umbraco node?

Comment: No, and it's part of a shared library so i can't edit it.  I found a hack-ish solution that i'll post up as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Hack-ish solution that I went with.

We use a controller (extending Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController) to render  MyModel for the page.

I realized that, in the controller I can use CurrentPage to get the data, and place it in the ViewBag to display.  So in order to display the array of tick points:

`ViewBag.tickPoints = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue<string[]>("tickPoints");`